# SwiftUI ForEach Change Data Used

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm working on an app that will display some data I have collected into a Chart. Since there's quite a few different arrays I want to use, I want to be able to update the `ForEach` inside the chart to display the chosen array from a picker, but I'm not sure how to turn this string `selectedset` into something the `ForEach` can read and recognise as an array. Does anyone know how to do this?

```swift
private var dataSet1 = [/* set1 elements here */]
private var dataSet2 = [/* set2 elements here */]

@State private var selectedSet = dataSet1

var body: some View {
    Chart {
        ForEach(selectedSet, id: \.id) { data in 
            // REST OF FOREACH STUFF HERE
        }
        // Other Chart components or modifications can be added here
    }
}
```

I tried a couple different things, including putting `selectedset` into the `ForEach` by itself but it still didn't work.

Comment: Do the arrays share the same type?

Comment: Your state var `selectedSet` right now is of type `String`.  You can make it hold the full array by just saying `@State var selectedset = data1` Then you can use that directly in the `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned whether the data type is the same or not for each array, two cases are possible. You can handle something like this.

**Case 1: If DataType is same for each array**

```
private var dataSet1: [DataType] = [/* set1 elements here */]
private var dataSet2: [DataType] = [/* set2 elements here */]

@State private var selectedSetType = dataSet1
@State private var selectedDataSet: [DataType] = []

var body: some View {
    Chart {
        ForEach(selectedDataSet, id: \.id) { data in 
            // REST OF FOREACH STUFF HERE
        }
    }
}


func updateSelectedArray() {
    switch selectedSetType {
    case dataSet1:
        selectedDataSet = dataSet1
    case dataSet2:
        selectedDataSet = dataSet2
    // Add more cases for additional datasets if needed
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

**Case 2: If DataType is different for each array**

```
@State private var dataSet1: [DataType1] = [/* set1 elements here */]
@State private var dataSet2: [DataType2] = [/* set2 elements here */]

@State private var selectedSet = dataSet1

var body: some View {
    Chart {
        switch selectedSet {
        case let dataSet1 as [DataType1]:
            ForEach(dataSet1, id: \.id) { data in 
                // FOREACH STUFF
            }
        case let dataSet2 as [DataType2]:
            ForEach(dataSet2, id: \.id) { data in 
                // FOREACH STUFF
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```